# Why is my memoized React component still re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I'm trying to understand React.memo but a bit puzzled. Thought the use case was preventing re-renders by memoizing the component? I have a memoized Child that is still being re-rendered every time.

--App

----Home [updates state via button click]

------Child [memoized to prevent re-renders but still re-rendering every time]

To my mind, the flow should work like this:

- user clicks button
- Home updates local state, increments number +1
- this triggers re-render of component and its children
- the memoized component is returned, old console log either appears or nothing appears because args havent changed for that component.

Whats actually happening:

- user clicks button
- Home updates local state, increments number +1
- this triggers re-render of component and its children
- the memoized component is returned, logs out afresh.

```
const MemoizedChild = React.memo(ShoppingBasket);

function Home() {

    const [ myNum, updateMyNum ] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="home__container">
        I am the home page
        <p>myNum {myNum}</p>
        <button onClick={() => updateMyNum(myNum + 1)}>Add Number</button>
        <MemoizedChild items={[1, 2, 3, 4]} total={900} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

log appears new/fresh each time, child re-rendered every time...

```
function ShoppingBasket({ total, items }) {
    console.log("Re Rendered Shopping Basket" + Date.now());
    return (
        <div className="basket__container">
            <h4 className="basket__heading">Shopping Basket</h4>
            <p className="basket__info">Total: ${total}</p>
            <p className="basket__info">No. of Items: {items.length}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Have i misunderstood something?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is a new array every render.  You might want to use `useRef` to store your array.

Comment: @Keith i thought the prohibition of re-rendering was based on whether the args were the same arguments, not whether they were different instances of the same information?

Comment: Yes,  in Javascript `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is not equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`..  Because both are completely new arrays, so are not equal.  UseMemo like most things in React only do a shallow compare.  So for example if you say put this in your browsers console.  `[1,2,3,4] === [1,2,3,4]` you will see it returns false.

Comment: @Keith How would you use useRef to pass that down though? let arr = useRef([1, 2,3 ,4]) and then pass arr as a prop to the Basket?

Comment: Yes,..  and then just do `<MemoizedChild items={arr.current} total={900} />`   Doing this will mean the array is always the same instance.

Comment: @Keith interesting... so an array arg is always different even when the values are the same. But the numerical arg passed to the `total={900}` prop doesnt behave the same way / doesn't require the useRef treatment. So this is very much a Javascripty thing relating to arrays/objects occupying a specific piece of memory?

Comment: Yes, it's a JavaScript thing, objects in JS are reference types, and arrays are objects.  Numbers are literal types.  Also remember `[]` is just shorthand for `new Array ()`, this might help visualise why `[] === []` equals false & `900 === 900` equals true.

Comment: @Keith Perfect, thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, i know this is a year old, I find this comment helpful so could the questioner or the commenter post this as answer. Might help people like me stumbling on this problem.